# splitting mysql col with csv values into respective fields

Tags: mysql, csv, split

I have a mysql table called "match"

there are 5 fields in match (4 blank col's and one col with CSV data)
load,username,username_clean,user_id,member_id

In the load field are many rows with comma separated values (CSV)
values in load column are in this format username,username_clean,user_id,member_id
that's 4 csv values in the first column "load"

QUESTION: How can I split the 4 values in load and place them in their respective columns?

Please help! Thank you in advance. 
example. I want the following

```
|Sara,sara,60,9|
```

to become: 
    
    
    Sara|
    
    sara|
    
    60|
    
    9|
    
    
     <--4cols instead of 1

Comment: How many rows in the table ?

Comment: a lot. More than 30K+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `match` SET
    username=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1),
    `load`=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1)
;
UPDATE `match` SET
    username_clean=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1),
    `load`=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1)
;
UPDATE `match` SET
    user_id=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1),
    member_id=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1)
;
```

or

```
UPDATE `match` SET username=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1);
UPDATE `match` SET `load`=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1);
UPDATE `match` SET username_clean=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1);
UPDATE `match` SET `load`=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1);
UPDATE `match` SET user_id=LEFT(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)-1);
UPDATE `match` SET member_id=SUBSTR(`load`,LOCATE(',',`load`)+1);
```

Since my first attempt added a comma, just run this

```
UPDATE matchindex SET
    username = REPLACE(username,',',''),
    username_clean = REPLACE(username_clean,',','')
;
```

Comment: sql on your first one gives error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match SET
    username=LEFT(load,LOCATE(',',load)),
    load=SUBSTR(load,LOCAT' at line 1

Comment: second idea gives error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match SET username=LEFT(load,LOCATE(',',load))' at line 1

Comment: MATCH is a function for FULLTEXT operations (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match). I added backquotes around the word `match`. Please try again.

Comment: still no luck. both ideas returning errors #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load,LOCATE(',',load)),
    load=SUBSTR(load,LOCATE(',',load)+1)' at line 2

Comment: Ugh LOAD is a reserved word too.

Comment: maybe I am running an old version of MySql?

Comment: I can rename the load field to anything I want

Comment: I just put backquotes around load. It is a SQL command (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Rolando you almost nailed it. The only issue is that it brought in the comma. anyway to keep the comma from carrying over into the respective fields? ex 'sara,' should be 'sara'

Comment: Fixed it. Added a `-1` to specific places. Try it again, please.

Comment: On second thought, you cannot do it again unless you reload the matchindex column with the old values.

Comment: BAAAAAAAM!!! you rock!!! Thank you a million times. Exactly what I needed to do and I just learned a lot. Thank you!!

Comment: I added code to strip the commas from `username` and `username_clean`.

Comment: thanks, I just dropped the table and started over the the strip comma code was a nice thought. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
define a function strSplit:

```
CREATE FUNCTION strSplit(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), pos int) returns varchar(255)
return replace(substring(substring_index(x, delim, pos), length(substring_index(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

use this query:

```
 update match set username=strSplit(load, ',', 1),username_clean=strSplit(load, ',', 2),user_id=strSplit(load, ',', 3),member_id=strSplit(load, ',', 4);
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match set username=strSplit(load, ',', 1),username_clean=strSplit(load, ',', 2),' at line 1

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match set username=strSplit(load, ',', 1),username_clean=strSplit(load, ',', 2),' at line 1

Comment: you are using sql or mysql?